# Crontab command to start jboss server after every reboot

Tags: linux, cron

Suppose my jboss server is running at below path - /usr/local/share/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/init.d
and want to start the same after every reboot
some have some crontab command for same

Comment: Would not be better if you create OS service and set it up to autostart after reboot? Is there any specific reason why you want use cron?

Comment: actually we have one VM where this server is hosted
and the VM gets auto shut down every day so to start JBoss automaticallyafter VM auto start need cron command